# Animated scrolling in ScrollView

Tags: android

I have a ScrollView with some EditTexts in it. If I click on one of the EditTexts, software keyboard opens and the ScrollView scrolls so that the EditText is at the top. The scroll is not animated - the EditText just "jumps" to the top, which doesn't look nice. Can I make it animated?